# magento product grid pagination and searching in edit page tab in custom module

Tags: magento, search, grid, pagination

Can anyone help me?

I have created custom module that uses product detail. I have used product grid in add/edit page to select product and it is working fine but the problem is "product grid pagination and searching is not working" it forwards me to client side when ever I click on pagination and search button on product grid.

To create product grid in add page tab, I have created one block page with `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and override all grid method. Actually I have paste `core/Mage/adminhtml/block/catelog/product/grid.php` code in my file.

I know the problem that `getGridUrl()` method does not finding the productcontroller url, thats why the pagination and sorting is not working.

I want product grid with custom column so I cant reuse main product grid. I must have to create my own product grid.